# find a substring which is palindrome in given string

Tags: java

input is :levelmm
output is: the given string is palindrome because the given string contains level is a palindrome remain character like mm is neglected.

package example;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class exp2 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("enter the string");
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    String s=scan.nextLine();
    String t="";
    String s1=s.substring(0, s.length()-1);

    for(int i=s1.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
{
    t=t+s.charAt(i);
}

    if(t.equalsIgnoreCase(s1))
    {
        int count=t.length();
        System.out.println("is palindrome"+(count-1));
    }else
    {
        System.out.println("not a palindrome");
    }
}
```

}
but its not working completely..

Comment: what are you trying to do ? what is your problem ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: The problem is not clear. Explain it better.

Comment: *"its working completely"* So why are you here, if the code is working? And if it is not working, try **debugging** the code. E.g. print the value of `t` and `s1`. --- Though I do wonder why you're removing the last character. *Hint:* Read the javadoc of [`nextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the line `String s1 = s.substring(0, s.length() - 1);` removes one character from your word, which is not something that looks like it's supposed to happen.

What it looks like is that you want to create every possible substring of an input and see if that is a palindrome. To see whether something is a palindrome I propose this:

```
private static boolean isPalindrome(String word) {
    String reverseWord = "";
    for (int i = word.length() - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        reverseWord += word.toCharArray()[i];
    }
    return reverseWord.equalsIgnoreCase(word);
}
```

Getting every single substring is more difficult, but can be done like this:

```
private static String[] allSubstrings(String word) {
    int amount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length() + 1; i++) {
        amount += i;
    }
    String[] res = new String[amount];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < word.length() + 1; j++) {
            res[index] = word.substring(i, j);
            index++;
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

Now, since every word that is 1 long is a palindrome, we don't want that, so in the main method we can say a word has to be more than 1 long. This results in a main method like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("enter the string");

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = scan.nextLine();

    boolean isPal = false;
    for (String word : allSubstrings(s)) {
        if (word.length() > 1 && isPalindrome(word)) {
            isPal = true;
        }
    }
    if (isPal) {
        System.out.println("Is palindrome");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Is not palindrome");
    }
}
```

I hope this answers your question and I wish you happy coding.